# How to resize multiple png files with parallel command and keep a part of name from the source file?

Tags: linux, imagemagick-convert, gnu-parallel

I have 100 png files in the same Linux folder and I want to create thumbnails from them.
For example the source files are:

```
page_1.png
page_2.png
...
page_100.png
```

I want to create 100 thumbnails in the same folder with the names like:

```
thumbnail_1.png
thumbnail_2.png
...
thumbnail_100.png
```

I tried the next command:

```
ls -1 page_*.png | parallel -j 3 convert {} -resize 120 thumbnail_{.}.png
```

but the created files are named as

```
thumbnail_page_1.png 
thumbnail_page_2.png
...
thumbnail_page_100.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a perl expression to get the effect :

```
parallel -j 3 convert {} -resize 120 {= s/page/thumbnail/ =} ::: page_*.png
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it.

Comment: @IulianBoiculese, feel free to accept it as answer.

Comment: You can save a process, and some typing and avoid parsing the output of `ls` with `parallel ... ::: page_*.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, exact, thanks.